# server not importing pictures from rss xml feed

Tags: php, xml, linux, apache, fastcgi

here's the problem:

i have a 3rd party script for my website... i have bought hosting from enom.com (i hope this doesn't offend anyone)

i installed the script and works great, except when i try to import rss feeds from other websites.

it's importing the xml file, except the images. The url path is correct, the image exists....

trying to figure out what is wrong, i installed "wamp" on my computer, installed the script and on localhost from my computer the import xml is working perfect, it downloads and add the picture into database + folder

i assume this is a hosting issue, and i want to fix it, can anyone point me where to look?

the hosting plan is using PHP Support as FastCgi application (php safe mode on)
"Server API     CGI/FastCGI"
on localhost i have php support on apache
"Server API     Apache 2.0 Handler "

thank you!

Comment: Please Add your script and XML url...

Comment: Sorry - my crystal ball seems a little clouded today...

Comment: it's encrypted with ioncube... i can't see the acutal php code...

Answer (score 0):

the answer is very simple, change the hosting company, or pay attention when you place your order.
It's related to `allow_url_fopen` setting which caused the problem.
in my case i couldn't modify the php.ini file because this was the hosting company policy...
however php.ini can be "bypassed" or modified for each php file by calling the "ini_set" php function which is available for php4/php5 engines...
here's an example

```
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);
if (ini_get("allow_url_fopen") == 1) {
echo "allow_url_fopen is ON";
} else {
echo "allow_url_fopen is OFF";
}
print ini_get("allow_url_fopen");
```

and it didn't work for me, because of the hosting company policy...

it can be also "bypassed" or modified by adding one simple line to .htaccess file

```
php_value allow_url_fopen On
```

but again, this wasn't an option for me...

***CONCLUSION: pay attention when you purchase hosting packages!!!***

As for those who can't understand when you can't paste your code as an example because is under specific license and it also encrypted with ioncube, before you post comments sit back and think before you act / or simply do something else...